# density of low degree factors of X^N-1 in finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let N be an exponential number of the order O(p^n) for some p and n. How to estimate the density of (or as fraction of N) cardinalities of subsets of polynomials f(X) in GF(p)[X] such that

1.f(X) is irreducible in GF(p).
2. f(X)|(X^N-1) (f(X) divides X^N-1).
3. Degree of f(X)<O(n^k) (polynomial order in n).

Comment: Don't expect simple asymptotics, it depends on complicated properties of $N$ and $p$: if $N$ is prime and $p$ has order $N-1$ modulo $N$ then $\frac{X^N-1}{X-1}\in \Bbb{F}_p[X]$ is irreducible.